# Recount ID's of array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have to following array:

```
array (
    array(
        "id" => "1",
        "items" => array(
            // items array
        ),
    )
    array(
        "id" => "2",
        "items" => array(
            // items array
        ),
    )
    array(
        "id" => "3",
        "items" => array(
            // items array
        ),
    )
    array(
        "id" => "4",
        "items" => array(
            // items array
        ),
    ),
)
```

Now after the an item is moved to another ID and one of the ID's has no articles in it, it'll be removed from the array, so as an example the array ID 3 will be removed. Now the ID's are 1,2 and 4. I need to recalculate them after one get's removed and make the ID's show as 1,2 and 3.

I need someone to point me in the right direction, just a suggestion on how to start, I don't want to receive a read-to-use code as I won't learn from it.

What do you think? Do I need to loop trough this array and fill a new array which will be saved again? Or is their a function I don't know about which could make this much easier?

Comment: if changing the order will not make any effect, then you can just assign the id of last item to the id which is deleted.

eg. if there are 1,2,3,4,5,.....100 and if you want to delete the item with id=36, just assing the last(i.e id=100 to id=36)

Comment: if this is your full structure, you could reduce one layer by using the `id` value as `key` for your `items` array.

Answer (score 0):

you can recalculate the numbers from the beginning

```
$new_arr = array();
$i = 1;

foreach($old_arr as $old_val) {

    $new_arr[$i]['id']  = $i;
    $new_arr[$i]['items']  = $old_val['items']; 
    $i++;
}
```